# Is it possible to determine how the steel was made, having its microstructure (for example, to distinguish forging from rolled products)?

Tags: steel, metallurgy, material-science

How do you think the steel in these images was made?

Example1
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZLRM.jpg)

Example 2
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrDE7.jpg)

Example 3
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpl2d.jpg)

Example 4
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6uhE.jpg)

Example 5
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBjaj.jpg)

Example 6
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1TcC.jpg)

Example 7
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/x619Q.jpg)

Example 8
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUqWa.jpg)

phosphoric iron microstructure:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Steels are usually considered "as cast" or wrought. The microphotograph is overetched and either high magnification or coarse grained , likely had a heat-treatment. Cast or wrought would be identified by inclusion morphology , best seen in unetched condition. Modern steels are very clean so minimum inclusions to look for. Modern steels are also continuously cast and some mills have the ability to reduce the amount of inclusions in wrought material even more. Forged or rolled could be determined with low ,or no, magnification of a large etched crossection to look at grain flow . And the shape of the product would be a big clue. "How it is made" could also be asking if it is all scrap or virgin steel from ore. Chemistry would be most helpful for this.

Comment: Thanks.I think this is the microstructure of forged steel. Right?

Comment: No way to tell with this etch and mag. It reminds me of  oxy-cutting swarf with the large black apparent porosities.

Comment: Perhaps the magnification is small? I replaced it with another sample with a higher magnification. Can you see something now?

Comment: I would remove the etch and look at much lower magnification . This looks like 500 X +, , i would start at 25 X.

Comment: Yes, I have several with 25 X magnification. For example, this one.

Comment: It is over etched and that is made worse by high contrast picture , so very little can be learned other than it is steel.  Looking at the whole component would be the best way to  determine the production method. Looking at a metallographic sample is more of a classroom exercise. Actually that was one of my metallurgy classes : Given 10  unknown metallographic samples ,determine the metal and condition, etc.

Comment: I realized that those images were too contrasty. I tried to make them less etched and I think now we can say more confidently how they were made. Can you take another look and tell me what you think?

Comment: The new images show it is wrought , my guess would be rolled rather than forged. They also shown a great range of thermal history , could be heat-treatment or hot service. Looking at the component and some information on the service history would be necessary to make further conclusions.

Comment: Yes, I know where these samples were taken from. They are taken from pieces of armor dating back to the 15th-16th centuries. I would like to make sure that they are really originals, and not modern replicas. Can this information somehow make sense?

Comment: I think chemistry would be helpful  In the last hundred years steels have been gaining inadvertent alloy from scrap. Cr , Ni , Mo , Al,. V, W , Cb, Ti, indicate modern steel even less than 0.1 %. I am not sure what Mn and Cu levels indicate; they are certainly in modern steel but may also have been in old steel. This is a specialized area , possible a museum could recommend a consultant.

Comment: As I look at the photos with this info , I could believe these were hand wrought by blacksmiths . BUT no idea when. There is no sign of folding like Damascus blades.

Comment: Content of impurities like Si , S , P can also help. An electron microscope analysis if the inclusions would also help; Iron sulfide ( not Mn )and silicates would indicate old steel.

Comment: Thank you. I have learned the chemical composition of these slag inclusions of these steels. No alloying elements,such as Cr, Ni, Mo, Ti, V, W, Cb were found. But I want to add that they were contained in some amount in the iron ore itself. That is, the quality of German and Spanish weapons is largely due to the presence in the Spanish and German iron ores of a small fraction of nickel (literally a fraction of a percent).

Comment: Inclusion analysis was undertaken on various samples of armour(it can be divided into four or three groups):
 1. Iron oxide only-probably hammer scale, or corrosion.
 2. Iron silicate only-presumably smithing slag.
 3. The silicates of iron mixed with other metals, particularly Ca and Al- presumably a
 bloomery slag.
 4. The same as 3 but without Mn. It might be a finery slag, since the Mn (if present) would
 have been reduced in the blast furnace.
 Almost three-quarters of the inclusions were of type 3.
 P was also present, but rarely (I added a picture of microstructures at the end).